# How do I map the same child entity to different tables if it is appears under different entities in Entity Framework 4.3?

Tags: orm, entity-framework-4.1

I need to map the following class hierarchy using Entity Framework 4.3.

```
public abstract class Rule
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public abstract ICollection<Parameter> Parameters {get;set;}
}

public class Entity1
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Rule> Rules {get;set;} 
    // Map Rule to table Entity1Rules and    
    // Parameters to table Entity1RuleParameters
}

public class Entity2
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Rule> Rules {get;set;} 
    // Map Rule to table Entity2Rules and    
    // Parameters to table Entity2RuleParameters
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This is called "polymorphic relationships", a pattern that can be accommodated by [various data models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895806/how-to-implement-polymorphic-associations-in-an-existing-database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. Each entity can be mapped only once. It would require you to involve some inheritance in `Rule` and `Parameter` classes but at the end your `Entity1` and `Entity2` will need to reference derived rule to set correct structure.