# Best way to mix polymorphic association and hierarchies?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Assuming the base table design (no. 3) from this link:

[What is the best way to implement Polymorphic Association in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7000283/1284817)

[image]

I would like to add (to the object table) a `ObjectType` and a `parentObjectID` for each `object.ObjectID`. I need this because I have objects that are children to other objects. These child objects can have child objects only of different types (different from self type).

So is it a good idea to put the names of the tables in the `objectType` column? This may be bad for security to store some of the schema in a table... Any other approach that I can use?

Here is an example :

Table Posts    -> id  | ObjectID(fk ref. Object.ObjectID)  |  Content
 Table Comments -> id  | ObjectID(fk ref. Object.ObjectID)  |  Posted_on_ObjectID(fk ref. Object.ObjectID)  |  Content

Basically posts and comments will be unique entities in Object super table . But because the comments can be made only for post entities and not for comments entities i have to store the types for each entity(ObjectID).

Comment: I assume Object1, object2 etc are types of objects defined in your parent Object table. Do you want to **Dynamically Create** new tables if new object types are added in parent table??

Comment: @jerrymouse No , for example : we have comments object and post object. Comments are allowed on post objects but not on comments objects. Thats why i need to store the types.

Comment: you should have mentioned this example in your question for a better answer. In this case I think you will have to define separate  tables for each object type. What does this line mean: `These child objects can have child objects only of different types.`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this in single table, by defining a self foreign key.

```
Objects | id | parent_object_id | name
--------+----+------------------+-----------------------------
           1 | NULL             | Object1 
           2 | NULL             | Object2
           3 | NULL             | Object3
           4 | 1                | Child Object of 1 
           5 | 2                | Child Object of 2
           6 | 3                | Child Object of 3 
           7 | 4                | Sub Child Object of 1 -> 4 
           8 | 5                | Sub Child Object of 2 -> 5
```

Comment: Yes, but is it good to store table information in another table (security reasons)? I asked this in the end of the question ?

Comment: Security related questions are not trivial to answer. In your case I wouldn't worry about embedding application specific things in the database. Securing the database server should be someone else's job.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Yes i had doubts too if i should model the db to make it easyer for application rules (was thinking about performance). Ill leave this rule only on application lvl then.