# Is it possible to link a table based on the role?

Tags: sql, sql-server, erd

I have 4 tables

- Account
- Admin
- User
- Role

The account table contains the email and password to login.
An account can either be an admin or an user.
An user has a `registerdate`
An admin has an `adminnumber`, but no `registerdate` (different attributes)
The role table contains the `role name`, either admin or user.

An account currently contains foreign-key relationships with all other tables. This isn't ideal, since depending on the role, one of the tables will be left empty.

I need all account to be in the same table, yet depending on the role it should have different links and attributes.

What is the best way to tackle this?

I use MSSQL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to implement Polymorphic Association in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000283/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-polymorphic-association-in-sql-server)

Comment: Recommended method is to add a `UserOrAdmin` table, to which `Account` has a FK to, and then `User` and `Admin` both have their primary keys foreign-keyed to that table (in other words they have a PK which is also a FK). You may also want a `Type` column

Comment: _and password to login_ I hope not. That is poor security. It should contain a hashed value. See [how to store passwords](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/store-password-database/)