# One field with two references in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Address (
  ResidentID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  Location varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  KEY ResidentID(ResidentID)
);

CREATE TABLE Customer (
  CustomerID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  ContactName varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
);

CREATE TABLE Supplier (
  SupplierID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  SupplierName varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (SupplierID)
);
```

I want to store CustomerID and SupplierID in the Address.ResidentID field with using of foreign keys:

```
ALTER TABLE Address ADD CONSTRAINT fk_CustomerID1 FOREIGN KEY(ResidentID) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID);
ALTER TABLE Address ADD CONSTRAINT fk_SupplierID1 FOREIGN KEY(ResidentID) REFERENCES Supplier(SupplierID);
```

But second 'ALTER TABLE' raises **Error: relation already exists**

Any suggestions?

Data example:

```
CustomerID  ContactName
C0001       Den

SupplierID  ContactName
S0001       John

So Address table should contains:

ResidentID  Location
C0001       Alaska
S0001       Nevada
```

Comment: I ran this in my local, did not get any error.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want a single Address entry to ALWAYS have corresponding Customer AND Supplier entries? I would think that a Customer may or may not have an address, and a a Customer may or may not be a Supplier, which would allow you to relate both Address and Supplier to Customer; Address seems to be a strange place to tie them both together.  However, if the intention is that the address is associated to one OR the other, a different field should be added for each.

Comment: @Sharique, I tested it too, and I got no error either.  Something is wrong in this question.

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin. I've ran my code and there was no errors. Then I've opened designer and there was no relation between Address and Supplier tables. But when I've make a dump on the database, both constraints were generated

Comment: Please have a look at the SQLFiddle I edited into my answer.

Comment: This error is not a MySQL error.  But it is a PostgreSQL error when you try to create a duplicate name for a constraint.  I think you are mixed up about which RDBMS you're using.

Comment: @BillKarwin The OP is using phpMyAdmin, afaik that does not combine with Postgres.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer, I just grepped the MySQL 5.6.13 source tree and the error message "relation ... already exists" is not in the source.  But if you Google for "postgresql relation already exists" you find a lot of matches, including some questions on StackOverflow.  So the OP may be using phpMyAdmin to *an* instance of MySQL, but this is not where the error is coming from.

Comment: @BillKarwin looks like you are right. Good point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either reference addresses from the Customer / Supplier (if they only have one) or two different columns.

The reason you see in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70e43/1/0) You cannot `INSERT` the required columns into the `Address` table if the `ResidentID` references BOTH tables. You could only insert lines that would match the contents of `Customer` AND `Supplier` but you want an OR connection that you can't create that way.

(Note: In my solutions I assume addresses to be optional. As [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/401246/tom) pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057188/one-field-with-two-references-in-mysql/19057464?noredirect=1#comment78492083_19057464) that may not be what you wanted, or expected. Make sure to mark the FK Columns in the first solution as `NOT NULL` if you want addresses to be mandatory, its more complicated for the second one. You have to mind the correct insertion order then.)

Either:

```
CREATE TABLE Address (
  AddressID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  Location varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (AddressID)
);

CREATE TABLE Customer (
  CustomerID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  AddressID CHAR(5),
  ContactName varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
);

CREATE TABLE Supplier (
  SupplierID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  AddressID CHAR(5),
  SupplierName varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (SupplierID)
);

ALTER TABLE Customer ADD CONSTRAINT fk_AddressID_Cust FOREIGN KEY(AddressID) REFERENCES Address(AddressID);
ALTER TABLE Supplier ADD CONSTRAINT fk_AddressID_Supp FOREIGN KEY(AddressID) REFERENCES Address(AddressID);
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE Address (
  CustomerID CHAR(5),
  SupplierID CHAR(5),
  Location varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID, SupplierID)
);

CREATE TABLE Customer (
  CustomerID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  ContactName varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
);

CREATE TABLE Supplier (
  SupplierID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  SupplierName varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (SupplierID)
);

ALTER TABLE Address ADD CONSTRAINT fk_CustomerID1 FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID);
ALTER TABLE Address ADD CONSTRAINT fk_SupplierID1 FOREIGN KEY(SupplierId) REFERENCES Supplier(SupplierID);
```

Comment: +1 good advice, but I suspect it is not the actual root cause of the OP's question.  I think he is using two different RDBMS instances, one MySQL and one PostgreSQL, and he's confused about which one he's applying changes to.

Comment: NOTE: a) Since the 1st solution's FK Columns aren't defined as `NOT NULL`, it doesn't force C / S Table Row to have an A Table Row. b) Even if they were made `NOT NULL`, it would force each C / S Table Row to have an A Table Row but not vice versa. c) Since MySQL (and, btw, SQL Server also) forces PK Columns to be `NOT NULL`, the 2nd solution would actually implement an "AND" (unless dummy C and S Table Rows added which would still only force each A Table Row to have C and S but not vice versa). I believe OP wants "OR" connection *and* also a 1-to-1 relationship between A and either C "OR" S.

Comment: ^Or more precisely, I believe OP wants "XOR" connection and also a 1-to-1 relationship such that corresponding Rows must exist in "A and (C xor S)" Tables.  Neither solution (even with explicit / implicit `NOT NULL`'s and/or dummy Rows added) fully implements that requirement, although they do get much closer than the OP did.

Comment: @Tom Since the OP accepted the answer, it seems I hit what she wanted. But if you write an answer that covers your perspective, that would be great.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs: 1) The OP may not've been aware of the caveats I pointed out which, IMHO, are significant, and therefore, IMHO, should've been pointed out (for at least the OP if not also other readers) even if you thought the OP didn't require them.  That's assuming you were aware of those caveats.  If, on the other hand, even you (with your ~7 k more Rep Score) weren't aware of them, then that's even more reason to suspect the OP wasn't either when he made this the Accepted Answer.
2) I didn't write a separate Answer, because I don't have one that would address the caveats I pointed out.

Comment: @Tom I actually did not think that addresses where mandatory. Thanks for pointing out that this would be a valid interpretation. I've added a note in the answer. In my experience with SO, I would expect such a note to be a valid edit by other people as well. So feel free to add such an edit yourself, if you want to)

Answer (score -1):

The approach you're trying is (a) not possible and (b) undesirable even if it was possible.

The best approach is to have a CustomerAddress table and a SupplierAddress table, each with a single FK to the matching base table; or if you must, a cross-reference table with appropriate constraints.

If your motivation for having a single Address table was code reuse, you can still do that ... think in terms of a template xxxAddress table design that can refer to any base xxx table. You can write non-database code that treats the base table name as a parameter and then could handle any number of xxxAddress tables as you add more base tables over time.

Or if your motivation for having a single Address table was to simplify reporting, you can always create a view or stored proc that returns a union of all such tables + an added field to indicate the base table for each address row.

**Angelo I am revising this a bit based on your comment ---**

Angelo, I ran your sample code in a local MySQL instance (not SQLFiddle) and observed an error.

I was surprised (you learn something every day) that MySQL did allow two foreign key constraints to be defined on the same field; however when you attempt to insert data, when trying to point the FK to the Customer table, I get an error saying a foreign key constraint fails referencing the Supplier table; and vice versa for the insert trying to point the FK to the Supplier table.

So my revised statement is (a) it is possible to create the hydra-headed FK in at least some DBMSs -- verified in MySQL, MS SQL Server and Oracle -- although (b) this only makes sense to use when the foreign key can refer to the same logical entity by ID across multiple tables (e.g. to ensure there is a corresponding record in all required tables, for example); and (c) if used to refer to multiple tables where the primary key is NOT the same logical entity, only works if by chance the same primary key value just happens to exist in all referenced tables, which is likely to lead to subtle, hard-to-find errors.

In other words, your example would work when attempting to insert a record referring to Customer ID=3 only if there was also a Supplier ID=3, which are really logically unrelated.

So my slightly revised answer to the OP is, what you're trying to do is not possible (or logical) when the foreign key is referring to different ENTITIES, as in the OP example of Customers and Suppliers.

Comment: Angelo, I've run your sample code in a local MySQL instance (not SQLFiddle) and observed an error.  I was surprised (you learn something every day) that MySQL did allow two foreign key constraints to be defined on the same field; however when you attempt the insert, when trying to point the FK to the Customer table, I get an error saying a foreign key constraint fails referencing the Supplier table; and vice versa for the insert trying to point the FK to the Supplier table.

Comment: Yeah, thats a bite in the ass. I wrote about it in my answer (the "Reason" part). But it can be useful (not often, though)