# Laravel migration same foreign key dependency on 2 different tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 3 tables:

```
1) CourseA
2) CourseB
3) Orders
```

Here is the structure of **CourseA** table:

```
id | course_title 
1  | Maths
3  | Physics
```

Here is the structure of **CourseB** table:

```
id | course_title 
2  | Biology
6  | Physcology
```

Here is the structure of **Orders** table:

```
id | course_id | course_type 
1  | 1         | 1
2  | 2         | 2
```

(**Note:** course_type == 1 means the record belongs to CourseA table, & course_type == 2 means the record belongs to CourseB table).

Now here in Orders table, course_id is a foreign key depending on 2 different tables.

How can I use Laravel Migration for this type of scenario?

I tired something like this but its not working:

```
Schema::table('orders', function($table)
{
    $table->foreign('course_type')->references('id')->on('courseA');
    $table->foreign('course_type')->references('id')->on('courseB');
});
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: What is the difference between CourseA and CourseB? Why not merge them into a single table?

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper Actually they have different atributes thats why

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `column` then create foreign key in migration.
It should be :

```
Schema::table('orders', function($table)
 {   
      $table->bigIncreaments('id'); // not necessary 

      $table->bigInteger('course_type_a')->unsigned();
      $table->foreign('course_type_a')->references('id')->on('courseA');

      $table->bigInteger('course_type_b')->unsigned();
      $table->foreign('course_type_b')->references('id')->on('courseB');

 });
```

Comment: Can you please explain course_type_a & course_type_b?

Comment: You want to insert `CourseA` and `CourseB` `id` on `orders` table in a same time with 2 row, right? If `CourseA` & `CourseB` id are same then how do you know which `id` is from `CourseA` and which from `CourseB`? Thats why create different column for store different table id. I hope you understand now?

Comment: As you can see i already have a column with course_type followed by values 1 & 2

Comment: You want to make a column relation with 2 table. But you can just one column relation with 1 table, not 2. Hope this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547276/is-it-possible-to-reference-one-column-as-multiple-foreign-keys