# Composite Foreign Key to Dynamic Table, Bad Practice

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

First off, I am not a DBA, I am a C# developer.  I am working on a pretty complex web application and I want to start with a solid database. So here is my issue:
I am trying to create a Settings table that will hold settings for multiple objects. ie: User settings, Season settings, League settings, Team settings.

Instead of creating a table for each of those I would like to keep everything in the Settings table but I can't figure out how to create the foreign key.

My approach is to have three columns in the Settings table: TableName PrimaryKey ID.  These three columns would create a composite key that would reference the appropriate object.  Is my approach considered bad practice or am I on the right track?  Is there a way I can do this that will still work with entity framework?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2002985/861716) which is basically the approach Karwin described in his book *Sql Antipatterns*.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my way of handling this.

[image]

In this diagram, ConfigId is primary key which is used as an FK in Person table as EyeColor, BloodType, PersonType and many more. These columns also hold a Check constraint to ensure no value apart from eye color or corresponding column get stored based on ConfigType. However this comes at a cost of broader datatype which may be `smallint or int instead of tinyint`.

Only difference is, I am calling these settings as ConfigType in your case {User, Team, Season etc.} and any extension can be done by inheritance concept by creating another table using ConfigId as FK in child table.

Answer (score 1):

If you use inheritance, by default EF will use one table for the entire hierarchy. This is known as Table Per Hierarchy or TPH

```
public abstract class Setting
{
   public string Key { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class UserSetting : Setting
{
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public virtual User User { get; set; } 
}

public class SeasonSetting : Setting
{
   public int SeasonId { get; set; }
   public virtual Season Season { get; set; }
}
```