# Determine possible column values based on another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like this:

**table1**

```
+----+-----------+---+---+
| ID |   Type    | a | b |
+----+-----------+---+---+
|  1 | Location  | ? | ? |
|  2 | Equipment | ? | ? |
|  3 | Location  | ? | ? |
+----+-----------+---+---+
```

I want the columns **a** and **b** to be limited to a set of values, depending on the value of the **Type** column. <strike>The possible values should be stored in another table with the name of the **Type**.</strike>

So for example: ID 1 has Type **Location**, so the columns **a** and **b** can only take values from table **Location_table**, which could look like this

**Location_table**

```
+----+----+
| a  | b  |
+----+----+
| a1 | b1 |
| a2 | b2 |
+----+----+
```

So column **a** could take the values **a1** and **a2**.

My question is: is this in any way possible, if so, how?

**edit:** I realised that the "lookup" table isn't exactly what I wanted. I will have a table "a" and a table "b".

**Table a**

```
+----+-----------+-------+
| ID |   Type    | Value |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  1 | Location  | a1    |
|  2 | Location  | a2    |
|  3 | Equipment | a3    |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

**Table b**

```
+----+-----------+-------+
| ID |   Type    | Value |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  1 | Location  | b1    |
|  2 | Equipment | b2    |
|  3 | Equipment | b3    |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

So if an entry in table1 is of Type "Location", column "a" could get values "a1" and "a2" and column "b" can get value "b1".

I think that's more like it.

Comment: As it stands now, your proposed schema is not _relational_, since there is no way to connect a `Type` in `table1` to a row in the `Location_table`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - Conditional Foreign Key Constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002985/mysql-conditional-foreign-key-constraints)