# data scheme with Polymorphic Associations

Tags: mysql, cakephp, database-design

Yesterday i post a question i found it was not well described.
After long research i found the term "Polymorphic Associations".

I try to find as simple solution as possible:
[MySQL - Conditional Foreign Key Constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002985/mysql-conditional-foreign-key-constraints)

But in my case the serial number is very important.The guide says in the link : product_id(in my case) will handle this.
The problem is the product number is not exactly identify which ProductA or which ProductB was.

[image]

There is still problem that the implementation will be used in Cakephp which does not support composite primary keys..
Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP 3.0 supports composite PK's very well.

Also this would still work with CakePHP 2.x. `product_list_items` is just a join table with some constraints. [Check the manual how to save HABTM associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-belongstomany-associations). Your diagram will work without issues in CakePHP and you can save and read additional data from the join table.

Comment: so i can list in my order the serial number of ProductA or ProductB?